My Vue API client is getting data OK, and I have the logic to turn it into .csv, but I can't seem to work out how to download the file
DiscogsCSV is intended to do the following:

Take as input a .csv file, the first column of which contains valid discogs release IDs
Look these release IDs up on discogs API https://api.discogs.com/
Return as output a new .csv file, with discogs release data for various columns appended to the release IDs:

release_id
artist
format
qty
format descriptions
label
catno
country
year
genres
styles
barcode
tracklist
Here is my code:
App.vue
<template>
    <div>
        <button @click="downloadSampleInputFile">Download sample file</button>
    </div>

    <div>
        <FileUpload @file="setFile" />
    </div>

    <div>
        <p v-for="row of data" :key="row">
            {{ row }}
        </p>
    </div>

</template>

<script lang="ts">
import { defineComponent } from 'vue';
import FileUpload from '@/components/FileUpload.vue';
import { fetchRelease, parseCsvToArray } from "@/parser";
import { prepareDownload } from './components/PrepareDownload';
import { downloadSampleInputFile } from './components/DownloadSampleInputFile';

export default defineComponent({
    name: 'App',
    components: {
        FileUpload,
    },
    data() {
        return {
            data: null as null | string[],
        }
    },
    methods: {
        async downloadSampleInputFile() {
            const link = document.createElement('a');
            link.href = '/src/assets/test_5_lines.csv';
            link.target = '_blank';
            link.download = 'test_5_lines.csv';
            document.body.appendChild(link);
            link.click();
            document.body.removeChild(link);
        },
        async setFile(file: File) {
            this.data = await parseCsvToArray(file)
            console.log(this.data)
        },
        async fetchReleases(idList: string[]) {
            try {
                const releases = await fetchRelease(idList)
                console.log('Fetched releases from Discogs', releases)
                return releases
            } catch (err) {
                console.log('Failed fetching releases', err)
            }
        },
        async downloadCSV(releases: any[]) {
            prepareDownload(releases)
        },
        
    },
    watch: {
        data(data) {
            this.fetchReleases(data)
        }
    },
});
</script>

fetchRelease.ts
import { DiscogsClient } from '@lionralfs/discogs-client';
import { processReleaseData } from './ProcessReleaseData';

export default  {
  name: 'FetchRelease',
  methods: {
    fetchRelease
  }
}

const db = new DiscogsClient().database();

async function fetchRelease(releaseId: string): Promise<any[] | { error: string }> {
  try {
    const { data } = await db.getRelease(releaseId);
    return processReleaseData(releaseId, data);
  } catch (error) {
    return {
      error: `Release with ID ${releaseId} does not exist`
    };
  }
}

PrepareDownload.ts
import { ROW_NAMES } from './RowNames';

export default  {
  name: 'PrepareDownload',
  methods: {
    prepareDownload
  }
}

export function prepareDownload(releases: any[]) {
    const csvContent = "releases:text/csv;charset=utf-8," + ROW_NAMES.join(",") + "\n" + releases.map(e => e.join(",")).join("\n");
    const encodedUri = encodeURI(csvContent);
    const link = document.createElement("a");
    link.setAttribute("href", encodedUri);
    link.setAttribute("download", "my_data.csv");
    document.body.appendChild(link); // Required for Firefox
    link.click();
  }

I can get as far as console.log('Fetched releases from Discogs', releases), just fine, the data is in the console. But this bit isn't working. Any help please? TIA
    async downloadCSV(releases: any[]) {
        prepareDownload(releases)

Edit: very latest changes - https://github.com/steve-davey/discogsCSV

"isn't working" - in which way? You don't call downloadCSV anywhere

@EstusFlask - ah, right, so would that perhaps be a question of adding this.downloadCSV(data) to my watcher?

If it's intended to be always executed after await fetchReleases(data) then likely yes

I tried that but now I'm getting "Failed to launch 'releases:text/csv;charset=utf-8,release_id,artist,format,qty,format_descriptions,label,catno,country,year,genres,styles,barcode,tracklist%0A1%0A2%0A3%0A4%0A5' because the scheme does not have a registered handler." I guess that is a completely different problem though.

It should be "data:" and not "releases:", it's not an arbitrary word

I'm aware none of this is arbitrary, but it's not easy for me to work out what's going on. It's not helping that data is such an opaque variable name, but I seem to need to use it, because that's what the library I'm using requires. So now I have the headers and releaseIds being downloaded as a .csv, but it lacks all the release data that I'm actually trying to get, even though it is being logged in the console just fine. There are no errors showing in the console.

The correct url format is data:text/csv;... as said, it's a coincidence that you named variables the same way, their names are unrelated. This is the reason you get this error. Don't use console for debugging, it's unreliable for objects, it's unknown if it's the problem here because the question doesn't contain the last part with downloadCSV(data). But %0A1%0A2%0A3%0A4%0A5 part looks like data. If the problem persists with the mentioned problems being corrected, please, provide a way to reproduce

I see, I didn't realise about the coincidence you mention; got you now though. I don't know what you mean by "the question doesn't contain the last part with downloadCSV(data)" though? As far as reproducing it goes, the only way would be to clone the repo and run it yourself. I will add an additional link to another GitHub repo with the very latest changes to the question momentarily. Thanks.
